# How to get the neighboring counties of all counties based on the content of the file？

Tags: r, nearest-neighbor, r-sf

I have a shp file. I want to get the names of neighboring counties in all regions according to the latitude and longitude in the file. I found that some regions obviously have neighboring counties, but I didn’t get the neighboring counties when I ran the code. I don't know what was wrong.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)
library(sf)
library(readxl)

> county <-st_read('D:/county.shp',stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> neighbor_counties <- function(subcounty){
   name <- st_touches(subcounty, county)
   county[unlist(name), ]$NAME
 }

> output <- vector("list", nrow(county))
> names(output) <- county$NAME
> for (i in seq_len(nrow(county))) {
   output[[i]] <- suppressWarnings(neighbor_counties(county[i,]))
  }
> output
> head(output)

> neighbor <- output %>%
   ldply(data.frame) %>%
   set_names("ori_county", "neighbor_county")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not exactly reproducible, but we are lucky to have the `nc.shp` shapefile that ships with `{sf}` available.

So consider this code; it is built on `sf::st_touches()` function, with the county shapefile passed as argument twice (once for the touching counties, and once for the counties being touched). Sparse = TRUE makes it return a list of indexes of neighboring counties.

To find names of neighbors of a particular county you need to know the index of the county of interest, and then subset the list of neighbors accordingly. You will get indices of the neighboring counties.

As for the second part of your question (expressed in comments) = how to get from a list of indices to a data frame of neighbors - I suggest creating a function returning a data frame, and then applying it via `purrr::map_dfr()` to the vector of indices as starting points; consider the code provided and amend as necessary. It should give you a start...

```
library(sf)

shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) # included with sf package

# a list of neighbors 
neighbors <- st_touches(shape, # first 
                        shape, # second
                        sparse = T)

# neighbors of County Mecklenburg (as in Charlotte of Mecklenburg-Strelitz)

# index of Mecklenburg cnty
idx_strelitz <- which(shape$NAME == 'Mecklenburg') 

# index of neighbors of Mecklenburg cnty
nbr_mecklenburg <- neighbors[idx_strelitz][[1]]

# names of neighbours of cnty Meckl.
shape$NAME[nbr_mecklenburg]
# [1] "Iredell"  "Lincoln"  "Cabarrus" "Gaston"   "Union"   

# a visual check
plot(st_geometry(shape))
plot(shape[idx_strelitz, ], col = "blue", add = T)
plot(shape[nbr_mecklenburg,], col = "red", add = T)
```

[image: NC with red & blue counties]

```
# second question: get pairs of names as a data frame

# a function returning data frame of neighbors of a given cnty
nbr_pairs <- function(idx)  {
  data.frame(ori_county = rep(shape$NAME[idx], length(neighbors[[idx]])), 
             neighbor_county = shape$NAME[neighbors[[idx]]])
}

# check - cnty Mecklemburg
nbr_pairs(idx_strelitz)
#    ori_county neighbor_county
# 1 Mecklenburg         Iredell
# 2 Mecklenburg         Lincoln
# 3 Mecklenburg        Cabarrus
# 4 Mecklenburg          Gaston
# 5 Mecklenburg           Union

# apply to list of indices
pairs_of_names <- purrr::map_dfr(seq_along(neighbors),
                                 nbr_pairs)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help very much. But if I want to get the corresponding neighboring counties of all regions, and finally store the results in a data frame, what should I do？

Comment: @user14345711 - I have amended the answer to show a possible approach to getting a data frame of name pairs from the list of indices

Comment: Thanks for your help very much. I have obtained the neighboring counties form for all counties. But I found that the result is consistent with the result obtained by my previous code. Some counties clearly have neighboring counties, but the results show that there is no. Should I not use st_touches()?

Comment: could you give an example? This may be caused by problems in underlying topology (county polygons seemingly touching, but with some tiny distance - a meter or so - that causes the st_touches to fail).

Comment: I don't know how to share pictures.

Comment: Give me some names then - NC counties that you expect to be neighbors

Comment: ”鼓楼区“、”平潭县“、“盘龙区”、“官渡区”、“嵩明县”.  These areas are incorrect parts of neighboring counties